# How do I use the variable in this accessor?

Tags: c#, accessor

I am trying to use an accessor, as it seems to me that that is the only way to accomplish what I want to do. Here is my code:

Game1.cs

```
public class GroundTexture
{
    private Texture2D dirt;
    public Texture2D Dirt
    {
        get
        {
            return dirt;
        }

        set
        {
            dirt = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Main : Game
{
    public static Texture2D texture = tile.Texture;
    GroundTexture groundTexture = new GroundTexture();
    public static Texture2D dirt;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        Tile tile = (Tile)currentLevel.GetTile(20, 20);

        dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt");
        groundTexture.Dirt = dirt;

        Texture2D texture = tile.Texture;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (texture == groundTexture.Dirt)
        {
            player.TileCollision(groundBounds);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

}

I removed irrelevant information from the LoadContent and Update functions.

On the following line:

```
if (texture == groundTexture.Dirt)
```

I am getting the error

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D' and 'Game1.GroundTexture'
```

Am I using the accessor correctly? And why do I get this error? "Dirt" is Texture2D, so they should be comparable.

This using a few functions from a program called Realm Factory, which is a tile editor. The numbers "20, 20" are just a sample of the level I made below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8cO3.png

tile.Texture returns the sprite, which here is the content item Dirt.png

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, read it to fast. Where do you define your texture variable? Is that part of the parent class Game?

Comment: where is the "texture" definition?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: UPDATE: Edited my question with the texture definition and information about the external program I use.

Comment: have you tried: `if (texture == (groundTexture.Dirt as Texture2D))`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work. I get the following error: Cannot convert type 'ShovelShovel.GroundTexture' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion